# jQuery, Wordpress, redirect to a page and attach html data to div on new page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

is this something that is possible? I have a jQuery function set up that gets information from checkboxes and then passes it to another function that Wordpress then uses to perform a WP_USER_QUERY. My question is though, is there a way to redirect to a new page and then display the results of this WP_USER_QUERY in a div on this new page? What I have below does everything *except* display the actual data on the new page. :(

Thanks for any help!

Here is my code:

```
     jQuery(function($){
         var artistData = $("#seeOnTour").val();
         var list = $("input[name='seeOnTour']:checked").map(function() {
             return this.value;
         }).get();

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
            type: 'post',
            data: { action: 'ontour_map_filter', keyword: list},
            success: function(data) {
                        console.log(list);
                        window.location.replace("/artists-on-map/");
                        console.log(data);
                        $('#info').html(data);
            }
        });
     })
```

ontour_map_filter function:

```
    $artiststosee = $_POST['keyword'];
    $lookup = array();

    function console_log( $data ){
        echo '<script>';
        echo 'console.log('. json_encode( $data ) .')';
        echo '</script>';
    }

    foreach ($artiststosee as $artist){
        array_push($lookup, intval($artist));
    }
    
    console_log($lookup);

    // The User Query
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query(array(
        'include' => $lookup,
        'fields' => 'all_with_meta',
    ));

    if (! empty($user_query->get_results())){
        foreach ($user_query->get_results() as $user){

            $studioaddress = get_field('studio_address', 'user_' . $user->ID);
            $mailingaddress = get_field('mailing_address', 'user_' . $user->ID);
            $hostartist = get_field('host_artist_if_guest_artist', 'user_'.$user->ID);
            $studioname = get_field('organization__business_name', 'user_'.$user->ID);


            echo '<p>'. $user->first_name . '</p>';
            echo '<p>' . esc_attr($studioaddress['studio_street_address']) . '</p>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<h2>No Artists Found.</h2>';
    }
    die();
```

Comment: The whole point of Ajax is or was that you could change content of a page without redirecting or re-loading. If you're going to do that anyway, why not just run a simple php function with a redirect to the new page with the new data based on user action and submit of the checkbox form?

Comment: Thats a good idea, i'll just do that.